# Setup Emacs TRAMP to use psftp for ftp connection

Tags: tramp

I recently need to edit remote files a lot. Now I'm using FileZilla to edit files on SFTP server, but I want to use Emacs to connect to the server.

I think it should work with PuTTY's `psftp.exe`, but I don't know how to setup Emacs correctly.

One important detail: SSH support is disabled on the server. I'm running on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MS Windows, Tramp offers the `psftp` method. However, it uses internally PuTTY's `plink` command, which means you need remote ssh support.

On GNU/Linux systems, Tramp offers the `sftp` method. But this won't work on MS Windows.

Comment: Actually I've solved this issue by using Windows Subsystem for Linux. Even though it does not provide GUI, that works.